# jQuery Ajax load not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is my code:

#### `test.html`

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $(window).bind('hashchange', function(){
          $('#result').load('test2.html', function(){
            alert('Load was performed.');
          });
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
<body>
  <a href="#Test1">Test 1</a>
  <a href="#Test2">Test 2</a>
  <div id="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

#### `test2.html`

```
<h3>This is content from test2.html</h3>
```

I want to detect the specific page to load using window.hash in change. For instance if the user goes to `http://localhost/test.html#test2`.

The main container (result) in the page will do an Ajax load call to test2.html to get the content. I can't manage to get this simple code to work. I'd appreciate if someone can guide me in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: where is your code in test2.html?

Comment: Hi the code in the test2.html is just the h3 tag

Comment: Hi, i did get the alert.

Comment: @Slay If you get the alert `test2.html` has nothing inside.

Comment: Based on the path to test2.html, it needs to be in the same folder as test.html. If it is, what it's the response code for the ajax request? A program like firebug can show you this.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below :

```
window.onhashchange = function () {
    $('#result').load('test2.html', function(){
        alert('Load was performed.');
    });
};
```

Comment: This happens only once right? Or each time the hash is changed?

Comment: @PraveenKumar It bind the `hashchange` event handler on the window, each time the hash is changed.

Comment: tried but didnt work. the content in my test2.html is not loaded in.

Comment: @Slay It's wired if you get the alert, try to check the response.

Answer (score 0):

#### Two things:

1. First see if the `$(window).bind('hashchange', function(){})` is working or not. Try giving some dummy code like below:

   ```
   $(window).bind('hashchange', function(){
       alert("Hash changed!");
   });
   ```
2. Secondly, as [xdazz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/762073/xdazz) said, try giving in a combination of JavaScript and jQuery code:

   ```
   window.onhashchange = function () {
       $('#result').load('test2.html', function(){
           alert('Load was performed.');
       });
   };
   ```
3. I am able to get the update as well as get the change. Lemme confirm a few things.

   1. Are you loading the jQuery Library?
   2. Are you running it on a server or just calling by `file:///` protocol? Sometimes the latter doesn't work.
   3. I used this code in my local server with the same stuff what you have. It works for me!

      ```
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $(window).bind('hashchange', function(){
          $('#result').load('test2.html', function(){
            alert('Load was performed.');
          });
        });
      });​
      ```

   #### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2BrUG/